# How to remove all the “$oid” and "$date" in a .json file?

Tags: python, json, database, pymongo

I have a .json file saved in my computer that contains things like `$oid` or `$date` which will later cause me trouble in BigQuery. For example:

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "about": "some text",
  "creationDate": {
  "$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
  }
}
```

I want it to look like (so it’s not just removing some letters from the string):

```
{
  "_id": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff",
  "about": "some text",
  "creationDate": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
}
```

With Pymongo, one can do something like:

```
my_file['id']=my_file['id']['$oid']
my_file['creationDate']=my_file['creationDate']['$date']
```

How would this look without using Pymongo, since I want to first find such keys and remove all the problematic `$oid` or `$date`?

Edit: sorry for the bad wording, what I meant to say was whether it was possible to find the keys that contain these problematic $ without writing down every key in the dictionary. In reality, there are more files with huge tables and many of them can contain this.

Comment: "*Can I do this without using Pymongo? Or by using Pymongo but working with files from my computer?*" I'm sure you can! (Questions like "*is X possible?*" are poor fits for Stack Overflow, as the answer in software development is almost always "Yes, with enough time, money, and resources", and reads more closely to a thinly-veiled request to write your code *for* you, which Stack Overflow won't do. Edit your question to illustrate your attempts at solving this problem, along with an explanation of why these didn't meet your requirements. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something as shown below.

```
import json
file = open('data.json','r')
data = json.load(file)
for k,v in data.items():
    #check if key has dict value
    if type(v) == dict:
        #find id with $
        r = list(data[k].keys())[0]
        #change value if $ occurs
        if r[0] == '$':
            data[k] = data[k][r]
print(data)
```

seems like we get this output.

```
{'_id': '5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff', 'about': 'some text', 'creationDate': '2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z'}
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question: "sorry for the bad wording, what I meant to say was whether it was possible to find the keys that contain these problematic $ without writing down every key in the dictionary like we do in Pymongo. In reality, there are more files with huge tables and many of them can contain this."

Answer (score 2):

The `$oid` and `$date` fields appear when you use the default encoder using `bson.json_util.dumps()`.

If you have control over where these files come from, you might want to fix the "problem" at source rather than having to code around it. The following code snippet shows how you can implement a custom encoder to format the output how you need it:

```
import json
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient


class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        if hasattr(obj, '__str__'):  # This will handle ObjectIds
            return str(obj)

        return super(MyJsonEncoder, self).default(obj)


db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one({'Date': datetime.datetime.now()})
record = db.mycollection.find_one()
print(json.dumps(record, indent=4, cls=MyJsonEncoder))
```

prints:

```
{
    "_id": "60a55e3cea5bf57c79177871",
    "Date": "2021-05-19T19:51:40.808000"
}
```